# Java: find common characters in two strings

Tags: java, for-loop, char, indexof, charat

I'm asked to write a program that finds the common characters in two strings using the **indexOf(char)** method and a **for loop**. Here's what I have so far - the output comes out blank still.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ClassName {
   public static void main (String args []) {

   Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

   String a = "";
   String b = "";
   String c = "";

   System.out.print("Enter two words: ")
   a = input.nextLine();
   b = input.nextLine();

   for (int i = 0; i < a; i++){

      char ch = a.charAt(i);
      if (b.indexOf(ch) != -1){
         c = c+String.valueOf(ch);
         }
      }
System.out.print("Common letters are: "+c);
}
```

}

[output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNGXz.png)

I'm not sure where to go from here.

thanks

Comment: Liam, you should post all your code so we can see how you are printing out the text. Best practice here is to post ALL your relevant code.

Comment: Yes, put all your code. I tried to execute your above snippet of code in an online Java IDE and it worked perfectly fine. I initialized a and b to "table" and "cable" respectively. I got "able" printed for c. If it is not working for you, maybe there is something wrong in the way you initialize a and b.

Comment: This is the kind of questions that doesn't really need to be asked... if you use a debugger to step through your code, you will see what went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will duplicate common characters for example if you compare "**developper**" to "**programmer**" your result string will contain three time the e character

If you don't want that behaviour I suggest that you also use a Set like this:

```
public class CommonCharsFinder {

    static String findCommonChars(String a, String b) {
        StringBuilder resultBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        Set<Character> charsMap = new HashSet<Character>();
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
            char ch = a.charAt(i); //a and b are the two words given by the user
             if (b.indexOf(ch) != -1){
                 charsMap.add(Character.valueOf(ch));
             }
        }

        Iterator<Character> charsIterator = charsMap.iterator();
        while(charsIterator.hasNext()) {
            resultBuilder.append(charsIterator.next().charValue());
        }
        return resultBuilder.toString();
    }
    // An illustration here
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       String s1 = "developper";
       String s2 = "programmer";

       String commons = findCommonChars(s1, s2);
       System.out.println(commons);     
    }

}
```

**Result from the example:**

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the confusion all, still learning to use this site (and how to code obviously). And yes @alainlompo that was another requirement of the question - that seems to work. thanks!

Comment: @benny you are welcome, keep coming on stack overflow, it's a great place to learn and share :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CommonCharFromTwoString {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
       System.out.println("Enter Your String 1: ");
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
       String str1 = sc.nextLine();
       System.out.println("Enter Your String 2: ");
       String str2 = sc.nextLine();

       Set<String> str = new HashSet<String>();
       for(int i=0;i<str1.length();i++){
           for (int j = 0; j < str2.length(); j++) {
              if(str1.charAt(i) == str2.charAt(j)){
                  str.add(str1.charAt(i)+"");
              }
        }
       }

        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public Set<Character> commonChars(String s1, String s2) {
    Set<Character> set = new HashSet<>();
    for(Character c : s1.toCharArray()) {
        if(s2.indexOf(c) >= 0) {
            set.add(c);
        }
    }
    return set;
}
```

Comment: Simply posting some code isn't terribly helpful. Can you explain your code? That way others can understand and learn from your answer instead of just copying & pasting some code from the web.